# Unexpected '<' error in post by POSTMAN chrome app

Tags: php, json

//config.php file

```
    <?php
    define('hostname', 'localhost');
    define('username', 'root');
    define('password', '');
    define('db_name', 'tutorial2');
    ?>
```

//connection.php file

```
 <?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    class DB_Connection {
    private $connect;
    function _construct(){
        $this->connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, db_name) or die(" DB connection error");

    }
    public function get_connection() {
        return $this->connect;
    } 
    }
    ?>
```

//user_control.php file. I want to insert "email" and password address to my phpMyadmin-mysql database.

```
 <?php
    require_once 'connection.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json ');
    class User {
    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DB_Connection();
        $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
    }
    public function does_user_exist($email,$password)
    {
        $query = "Select * from users where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $json[success] = ' Welcome '.$email;
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }else {
            $query = " Insert into users(email,password) values ('$email','$password')";
            $is_inserted = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
            if ($is_inserted == 1){
                $json[success] = ' Account created, welcome '.$email;
            }else {
                $json[error] = ' Wrong password ';
            }
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }
    }
    }

    $user = new User();
    if (isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        $encrypted_password = md5($password);
        $user -> does_user_exist($email,$encrypted_password);

    }else {
        echo json_encode("You must fill both fields");
    }
    }
    ?>
```

after all of this [POSTMAN POST error. somehow i did by cleaning but it dosent save the "email" and "password" into database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKTBd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the reason:

```
if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)){
    $encrypted_password = md5($password);
    $user -> does_user_exist($email,$encrypted_password);
```

Remove the whitespaces: 
`$user->does_user_exist($email,$encrypted_password);`

Make sure there is no whitespace available before your starting `<?php`tag on all the files.

Also make sure your `$json` array keys are within `' (single quotes)` like this:

```
$json['success'] = ' Welcome '.$email;
$json['error'] = ' Wrong password ';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it is still  " Unexpected '<' "

Comment: can you make sure in all your PHP file's beginning, there's no whitespace before the `<?php` tag?

Comment: Sir still no change in output.

$json['success'] = 'Welcome';
$json['success'] = ' Account created, welcome ';
$json['error'] = ' Wrong password ';

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim,  please how did you fix this

Comment: @SKMishu please how did you fix this?

Comment: @Kennedy
Actually there was an issue in my connection script. This is it, it works well.

Comment: @SKMishu Thanks,i found my error, i had a password set for my root in php admin, while i was trying to access it , without password from mysql